# NAT/PAT port and address selection

Tags: networking, firewall, router, nat, pat

I am currently having some issues with TCP port reused too often (under 2 minutes) for a source NAT and I was wandering what is the algorithm used to select the IP and port for a SNAT.

Here is some context: I have an entire network (10.0.0.0/8, tons of users) accessing internet through one firewal (it happens to be a Fortigate).
We have a public address pool (let's says 1.2.3.0/27) to NAT all these clients IP addresses.

How will my router/firewall decide what IP address to NAT to and what source port to use?

Is this vendor specific? Do you know of any implementation that you could explain to me?

I hope my questions are clear :)

Regards,
Pierre

Comment: Sounds like a use-case for a http/https proxy.

Comment: There is actually a proxy, it is hosted somewhere on the internetz so I have only one destination for my NAT.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends from your device (firewall) configuration/behavior.
Eg. with a Linux firewall you can apply this configuration (with -j SNAT) to some matching rules, matching rules can check protocol, src/dst ports, src/dst address, maybe time of the day, etc..

Comment: Do you know the algorithm used in netfilter?
I was also looking for a possible RFC recommanding a way to do it if it exists.

Comment: From iptables manpage:
_If no port range is specified, then source ports  below  512  will  be mapped  to  other  ports  below  512: those between 512 and 1023 inclusive will be mapped to ports below 1024,  and  other  ports will  be mapped to 1024 or above. Where possible, no port alteration will_
In iptables you can specify port range with _--to-source_.
Some interesting information in [RFC5382](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5382)